# fullcalendar and bootstrap visible-print

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am trying to include two fullcalendars on one page. The first should only be visible on screen and the second should only be visible on print.

```
 <div class="hidden-print">
   <h1>This is hidden in print</h1>
   <div id="calendar"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="visible-print">
   <h1>This is visible in print</h1>
   <div id="calendar2"></div>
 </div>
```

But when I print the page, the second calendar is not visible and if I check the source the contents of the second calendar is not rendered. I created a plunk to demonstrate it: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/RQx1Up2Y1jbzs9Ixm2aX/

(code: http://plnkr.co/edit/RQx1Up2Y1jbzs9Ixm2aX)

It makes sense since this is expected behaviour according to the fullcalendar docs:

> "Notice that this example calls render whenever any tab is shown, not just the tab that the calendar is within. This is okay, because FullCalendar is smart enough to only render calendars that are visible to the user." http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/render/

Is it somehow possible to override this behaviour and put a fullcalendar within a "visible-print"-class anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a great answer and I would love to see a better one. But it should work if you have a fairly static fullcalendar.

Essentially, start with the FC outside of the `visible-print`, render it, then move it in.

```
$('#calendar2').fullCalendar({});
$('#calendar2').fullCalendar('render');
$('#calendar2').appendTo(".visible-print");
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgxP0ux7vX4kj9hyS9Y1?p=preview)

Note that every time you make a change to it, it will need to be moved out and rendered again.